# UItableview crash at cellForRowAtIndexPath because of my NSMutableArray containing special characters

Tags: xcode, json, uitableview, nsmutablearray, ios6.1

I am fetching data from web service and store on the `NSMutableArray`

```
app.firstName=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[[[luckyNumbers    valueForKey:@"findProviders"]valueForKey:@"quotes"]valueForKey:@"firstName"], nil];
NSLog(@"app.first %@",app.firstName);

app.first 
(
    (
    "Tom ",
    shamu,
    Shiva
    )
)
cell.Phone.text=[app.firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Console terminating the app due to the below uncaught exception:

> 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app.firstName at index 0 you now have an array.and you assign it display in a string .Hence the crash

`[app.firstName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` returns an array not a string.

Try

```
NSArray *tempArray=[app.firstName objectAtIndex:0];
cell.Phone.text=[tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I think you need to edit datasource methods for this change

Comment: that is what i said you hav to edit datasource method .Return this temparray count to numberOfRowsInSection method